# How to simplify my methods with tons of if statements

Tags: java

My code is supposed to read an input file and count the uses of each character in the file then print them all out. The code works but I know that there has to be a way to cut down on all the if statements. Right now I'm making methods for reading and one for output so its not all written in my main method. Any and all suggestions are helpful, thanks.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CharacterCounts {

    static int nl = 0;
    static int sp = 0;
    static int ex = 0;
    static int ap = 0;
    static int cm = 0;
    static int hy = 0;
    static int pd = 0;
    static int cn = 0;
    static int sm = 0;
    static int qu = 0;
    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 0;
    static int c = 0;
    static int d = 0;
    static int e = 0;
    static int f = 0;
    static int g = 0;
    static int h = 0;
    static int ii = 0;
    static int j = 0;
    static int k = 0;
    static int l = 0;
    static int m = 0;
    static int n = 0;
    static int o = 0;
    static int p = 0;
    static int q = 0;
    static int r = 0;
    static int s = 0;
    static int t = 0;
    static int u = 0;
    static int v = 0;
    static int w = 0;
    static int x = 0;
    static int y = 0;
    static int z = 0;
    static int A = 0;
    static int B = 0;
    static int C = 0;
    static int D = 0;
    static int E = 0;
    static int F = 0;
    static int G = 0;
    static int H = 0;
    static int I = 0;
    static int J = 0;
    static int K = 0;
    static int L = 0;
    static int M = 0;
    static int N = 0;
    static int O = 0;
    static int P = 0;
    static int Q = 0;
    static int R = 0;
    static int S = 0;
    static int T = 0;
    static int U = 0;
    static int V = 0;
    static int W = 0;
    static int X = 0;
    static int Y = 0;
    static int Z = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String file = args[0];
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileReader scanner = new FileReader(file);
        int i;
        while ((i = scanner.read()) != -1) {
            if ((char) i == '\n') {
                nl++;
            } else if ((char) i == ' ') {
                sp++;
            } else if ((char) i == '!') {
                ex++;
            } else if ((char) i == '\'') {
                ap++;
            } else if ((char) i == ',') {
                cm++;
            } else if ((char) i == '-') {
                hy++;
            } else if ((char) i == '.') {
                pd++;
            } else if ((char) i == ':') {
                cn++;
            } else if ((char) i == ';') {
                sm++;
            } else if ((char) i == '?') {
                qu++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'a') {
                a++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'b') {
                b++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'c') {
                c++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'd') {
                d++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'e') {
                e++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'f') {
                f++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'g') {
                g++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'h') {
                h++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'i') {
                ii++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'j') {
                j++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'k') {
                k++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'l') {
                l++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'm') {
                m++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'n') {
                n++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'o') {
                o++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'p') {
                p++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'q') {
                q++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'r') {
                r++;
            } else if ((char) i == 's') {
                s++;
            } else if ((char) i == 't') {
                t++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'u') {
                u++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'v') {
                v++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'w') {
                w++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'x') {
                x++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'y') {
                y++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'z') {
                z++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'A') {
                A++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'B') {
                B++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'C') {
                C++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'D') {
                D++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'E') {
                E++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'F') {
                F++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'G') {
                G++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'H') {
                H++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'I') {
                I++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'J') {
                J++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'K') {
                K++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'L') {
                L++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'M') {
                M++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'N') {
                N++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'O') {
                O++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'P') {
                P++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'Q') {
                Q++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'R') {
                R++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'S') {
                S++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'T') {
                T++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'U') {
                U++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'V') {
                V++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'W') {
                W++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'X') {
                X++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'Y') {
                Y++;
            } else if ((char) i == 'Z') {
                Z++;
            }

        }
        if (nl != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'/n' %d\n", nl);
        }
        if (sp != 0) {
            System.out.printf("' ' %d\n", sp);
        }
        if (ex != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'!' %d\n", ex);
        }
        if (ap != 0) {
            System.out.printf("''' %d\n", ap);
        }
        if (cm != 0) {
            System.out.printf("',' %d\n", cm);
        }
        if (hy != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'-' %d\n", hy);
        }
        if (pd != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'.' %d\n", pd);
        }
        if (cn != 0) {
            System.out.printf("':' %d\n", cn);
        }
        if (sm != 0) {
            System.out.printf("';' %d\n", sm);
        }
        if (qu != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'?' %d\n", qu);
        }
        if (A != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'A' %d\n", A);
        }
        if (B != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'B' %d\n", B);
        }
        if (C != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'C' %d\n", C);
        }
        if (D != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'D' %d\n", D);
        }
        if (E != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'E' %d\n", E);
        }
        if (F != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'F' %d\n", F);
        }
        if (G != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'G' %d\n", G);
        }
        if (H != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'H' %d\n", H);
        }
        if (I != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'I' %d\n", I);
        }
        if (J != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'J' %d\n", J);
        }
        if (K != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'K' %d\n", K);
        }
        if (L != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'L' %d\n", L);
        }
        if (M != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'M' %d\n", M);
        }
        if (N != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'N' %d\n", N);
        }
        if (O != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'O' %d\n", O);
        }
        if (P != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'P' %d\n", P);
        }
        if (Q != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'Q' %d\n", Q);
        }
        if (R != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'R' %d\n", R);
        }
        if (S != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'S' %d\n", S);
        }
        if (T != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'T' %d\n", T);
        }
        if (U != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'U' %d\n", U);
        }
        if (V != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'V' %d\n", V);
        }
        if (W != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'W' %d\n", W);
        }
        if (X != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'X' %d\n", X);
        }
        if (Y != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'Y' %d\n", Y);
        }
        if (Z != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'Z' %d\n", Z);
        }
        if (a != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'a' %d\n", a);
        }
        if (b != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'b' %d\n", b);
        }
        if (c != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'c' %d\n", c);
        }
        if (d != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'d' %d\n", d);
        }
        if (e != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'e' %d\n", e);
        }
        if (f != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'f' %d\n", f);
        }
        if (g != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'g' %d\n", g);
        }
        if (h != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'h' %d\n", h);
        }
        if (ii != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'i' %d\n", ii);
        }
        if (j != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'j' %d\n", j);
        }
        if (k != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'k' %d\n", k);
        }
        if (l != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'l' %d\n", l);
        }
        if (m != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'m' %d\n", m);
        }
        if (n != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'n' %d\n", n);
        }
        if (o != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'o' %d\n", o);
        }
        if (p != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'p' %d\n", p);
        }
        if (q != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'q' %d\n", q);
        }
        if (r != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'r' %d\n", r);
        }
        if (s != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'s' %d\n", s);
        }
        if (t != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'t' %d\n", t);
        }
        if (u != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'u' %d\n", u);
        }
        if (v != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'v' %d\n", v);
        }
        if (w != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'w' %d\n", w);
        }
        if (x != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'x' %d\n", x);
        }
        if (y != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'y' %d\n", y);
        }
        if (z != 0) {
            System.out.printf("'z' %d\n", z);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to print all characters or you could print only the ones that the string contains ?

Comment: My eyes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537270/read-a-text-file-and-store-every-single-character-occurrence

Comment: you could use an array to count the letters and index it with the ascii-code of the letter (minus some offset). Details are explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Comment: Best Question of the Day award.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily improved by using a `Map<Character, Integer>`. Change your declaration to this:

```
static final Map<Character, Integer> VALUES = new HashMap<>();
```

Then the body of your code can be changed to this:

```
Integer val = VALUES.get(i);
if(val == null) VALUES.put(i, 1);
else VALUES.put(i, val + 1);
```

Then simply iterate over it to display the values at the end.

Keeping the order, or restricting it to just those characters, could be done by using a `LinkedHashMap` and pre-populating all the desired values with zero.

Here's an example of what that would look like:

```
private static final Map<Character, Integer> VALUES = new LinkedHashMap<>();

static{
    for(char c : "\n !\\,-.:;?".toCharArray()){
        VALUES.put(c, 0);
    }
    for(char c = 'a'; c < 'z'; c++){
        VALUES.put(c, 0);
    }
    for(char c = 'A'; c < 'Z'; c++){
        VALUES.put(c, 0);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String file = args[0];
        FileReader scanner = new FileReader(file);
        int i;
        while ((i = scanner.read()) != -1) {
            Integer val = VALUES.get((char)i);
            if(val != null) VALUES.put((char)i, val + 1);
        }
        for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : VALUES.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue() > 0)
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

<s>^Untested, but should at least be close.</s> 
Now tested, and the numerous bugs have been fixed.

Same behavior, more maintainable, less likely to contain typos, and 10% of the typing.

Comment: Isn't `Character` instead of `Char`?

Comment: @AlexSifuentes Yeah, good catch. I think I corrected them all.